# how to have multiple arguments to multiple variables for a function

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to have multiple arguments through argparse to be used in a function
I want the arguments to be put in the function below

```
def toto(var1,var2,var3):
    print(var1,var2,var3)
```

This is my argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--names', type=str,nargs=1, help='<Required> Set flag')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Issue is I need three arguments.

I put the function in a file like `hello.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(args)
    if args.names:
        toto(var1,var2,var3)
```

I then run the command

```
python hello.py --names 'bobo'
```

I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 15, in <module>
    toto(var1,var2,var3)
NameError: names 'var1' is not defined
```

What is it happening and how can I add three arguments instead of one?

Thanks

Comment: Add a `print(args)` to your code.  I expect to see `Namespace(name=['bobo'])`.  You defined out argument, and specified `nargs=1`.  So `args.name` will be `['bobo']`.  I don't see where you expect to get `var1`, etc.

Comment: @hpaulj done. see updated code.

Comment: Seems like (a) syntax-error because neither of your vars like `var1` was assigned/defined, (b) the number of arguments was limited to `nargs=1` instead wanted `3`, (c) the parsed argument(s) `arg.name` was never passed to your function `toto` (not even transitively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to specify the number of arguments `argparse` should accept on the command line, in this case three so `nargs=3`.

```
parser.add_argument('--names', type=str,nargs=3, help='<Required> Set flag')
```

The variables will be stored in `args.names` which is a list in this case, so you can unpack that list into three variables:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if args.names:
        var1, var2, var3 = args.names
        toto(var1, var2, var3)
```

Finally, run it like below and it will give you the correct results:

```
~$ python hello.py --names 'babi' 'bibo' 'bobu'
babi bibo bobu
```

Comment: Your answer illustrates the [docs of `nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) well, .. but you either should refer to the argument by singular `args.name` or pluralize `'--name'` to `'--names'` which would well express the expected list. Would it then be correct to unpack like ` toto(*args.names)` ?

Comment: hi @hc_dev agreed for the name of the variable. For the docs, it does not seem to be that clear actually. My first attempt of the question was met with 'contempt', even if the word is strong but I stick to it. This is the reason I've figured out this question and answer to bring a bit more clarity on the topic.

Cheers.